# Does an iterator retain its own copy of an array in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple program here that deletes an element in a list, while using the iterator returned by `reversed()`.

The code is below:

```
def removeElement( nums, val ):
  for x in reversed(nums):
    if x == val:
      nums.remove(x)
```

If I was to iterate over the list using `for x in nums:`, then when an element is removed that is also the current element, we'll end up skipping elements in the array. This, however, doesn't happen in the case that we use the iterator returned by `reversed()` -- the calls to `remove()` seem to have no effect on the reversed list.

I also noticed each element in both lists have the same memory address, so an entirely new list isn't allocated by `reversed()`.

How does the iterator returned by `reversed()` retain the original structure of the list in spite of the calls to `remove()` that effect the original list?

Comment: You're breaking the number one rule of iterating: don't modify the thing you're iterating.

Comment: Regardless how you do it, it is *not* a good idea to iterate and change a collection at the same time.

Comment: The fact that the numbers within the list `nums` have the same memory address is  due to the way integers are cached and is not relevant

Comment: I'm aware of that. This code isn't actually being used, it's a contrived example to display the behaviour I'm confused about -- that the `reversed()` iterator seems to retain its own separate structure to the original list.

Comment: While the answers below have described how the specific iterator returned by calling `reversed` on a list works, in general there is no answer to the question asked in the title. While most iterators will only *reference* the underlying sequence they're iterating over (if there is one), that's not guaranteed by the Python language specification. It *is* possible for a custom iterator to copy data into its own storage. That would *probably* be a bad design, but maybe it could make sense in some situation.

Comment: I think some of the itertools functions such as `itertools.product` and `itertools.cycle` etc. do make a copy of the input iterable, to support repeated iterations of the same sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does an iterator retain its own copy of an array in Python?

**No**, or at least not in CPython. We can perform a simple test for lists:

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> for x in reversed(l):
...     l[0] = 3
...     print(x)
... 
2
3
```

Here we thus see that our edit (`l[0] = 3`) has impact on what element is been yielded. At the end we see `3`. If `reversed(..)` first constructed a copy, then it would emit `1`. For a list with one element, this would not work, since in that case, we set `x` to `1` *before* entering the body of the loop, and then changing the list, will have no effect on that element.

A list has defined a `__reversed__` function, which means that in case of a `reversed(..)` call, it will use this to enumerate the elements in reverse. One could implement this in Python like:

```
class list:

    # ...

    def __reversed__(self):
        for i in range(len(self)-1, -1, -1):
            if i >= len(self):
                yield self[i]
            else:
                break
```

In CPython, it is implemented with a [`listreviterobject` object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e281f7d80ce2584a7e6a36acffb5a9cd796a0fe2/Objects/listobject.c#L3204) wich in essence also has an index `it_index` that is [decremented when accessing the next item](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e281f7d80ce2584a7e6a36acffb5a9cd796a0fe2/Objects/listobject.c#L3296). I updated the Python version to make it more equivalent with the CPython implementation.

If you `.remove()` an element, then you remove the first item that Python finds, and it thus might "move" the elements under the cursor. As a result it is possible that we count the same item multiple times. This however will not have much effect in the end. For example:

```
1 4 4 2 4 4
```

if we remove `4`, we will do this in the following way:

```
1 4 4 2 4 4   (start cursor at the right)
            ^

1 4 4 2 4 4   (start cursor at the right)
          ^

1 4 2 4 4     (remove 4)
          ^

1 4 2 4 4     (advance cursor)
        ^

1 2 4 4       (remove 4)
        ^

1 2 4 4       (advance cursor)
      ^

1 2 4         (remove 4)
      ^

1 2 4         (advance cursor)
    ^

1 2           (remove 4)
    ^

1 2           (advance cursor)
  ^

1 2           (advance cursor)
^
```

So given the cursor is located on the element we aim to remove, we will remove the first occurrence of that element. This will always be located at the left (or under the cursor), since if the cursor is at the left of that place, it can not be placed over that element.

If it removes the element, one can say that a part of the list, moves "under the cursor". So that means that, since the cursor moves to the left, it stays relatively at the same place. This will keep happening until the last element is removed. Next the cursor can keep moving to the left, and will never see an element that can be removed anymore (since these are already removed).

A simple program that can yield *emperical* evidence that it works is the following:

```
while True:
    l = [randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10)]
    x = randint(0, 9)
    removeElement(l, x)
    assert x not in l
```

Here we thus generate a list of 10 random elements, and remove. At the end we check that `l` no longer contains an `x` element. This of course is *not* a fundamental proof that it works, but if we run this long enough, it at least gives us some evidence that it works for lists with 10 elements with values between `0` and `9`.

But that being said, it is better *not* to modify and iterate over a collection, regardless in what way, at the same time. If you later want to change the code to look for the current and next element, then this can go wrong.

Comment: Correction: `nums.remove(x)` actually removes the first instance of `x`, not whichever instance the iteration was on. The code happens to work anyway, but not in the way it appears to at first glance.

Comment: @user2357112: aarghh. yes :(

Comment: I don't think this answers the issue. The iterator returned by `reversed()` allows us to iterate from the end of the original list, but the call to `remove()` on the original list will remove the first occurrence of the given element encountered by a linear search from the beginning of the original list (going forwards, not backwards).

Comment: @bag: yes, but if you remove the first element, then one can say that although the cursor decrements, he stays "relatively" at the same place, and thus will keep removing until that element is no longer under the cursor.

Comment: The `reversed()` object seems to never raise `IndexError`, even if you change `nums.remove(x)` to `nums.clear()` in the question code. So that would be different from your python example implementation.

Comment: The problem that I'm seeing is that, even if the first element is removed for example, we'll still later visit that element in our iteration -- it was never removed from the perspective of the reversed iterator. If we iterate over a list of size 5, and delete 3 elements, our reversed iterator still does 5 iterations as if the removal of those elements never occurred.

Comment: @HåkenLid: that is because in CPython, it does do index checks *each* time: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e281f7d80ce2584a7e6a36acffb5a9cd796a0fe2/Objects/listobject.c#L3310

Comment: @bag: no, see the updated example. I've added an explanation why it exactly will remove all the instances.

Comment: Ah sorry, I hadn't noticed you updated the answer. That makes sense -- thank you!

Comment: Is this really just a CPython implementation detail? It seems sufficiently important that the behaviour might/should be guaranteed?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: well the documentation says: "Called (if present) by the reversed() built-in to implement reverse iteration. It should return a new iterator object that iterates over all the objects in the container in reverse order.". But I can not find any *documented* guarantees. So to the best of my knowledge, that means that although this is probably the most *sensical* way to do it, it is open to another implementation, but I agree that it makes sense to document the behavior.  But right now, I can not find it.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation of `reversed()` says:

> reversed(seq)
>
> Return a reverse iterator. seq must be an object which has a **reversed**() method or supports the sequence protocol (the **len**() method and the **getitem**() method with integer arguments starting at 0).

There don't seem to be any further guarantees about how the function is going to work in the documentation.

Gives that documentation I would expect that the trivial implantation of `reversed()` for a list like `A=("a", "b", "c", "d)` returns `A[3]`, `A[2]`, `A[1]` and finally `A[0]` and I see no reason why a given implemention would store the structure of the list.